# AVRCP volume change event fails in bluez 5.49

Tags: linux, bluetooth, timeout, bluez

While connecting device with One plus phones, I am facing volume sync issue. Phone does not give absolute volume changes to device.

I suspect while connection happening, Some capabilities exchange happens. At that time device fails to tell that it has a absolute volume event (AVRCP_EVENT_VOLUME_CHANGED). Because of that, device could not get volume changes event further.

I supposed to get **"profiles/audio/avrcp.c:handle_vendordep_pdu() AVRCP PDU 0x50, company 0x001958 len 0x0100"** this log in btmon while increase/decrease the volume from the phone's volume bar. I could not get this log/event.

One plus phone settings and all fine like it enabled with absolute volume in the developer option and Media volume sync is also enabled in the Bluetooth Advanced settings.

Note: Except one plus phone, Other phone models are working fine (Android and ios)

Do we have any patch for this in bluez ? Kindly help me if you have a solution

Thanks in advance